# SQL Server Data Tools - Data Link Properties - Server Name Drop Down Empty

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using VS 2019 with the latest version of SQL Server Integration Services Projects plugin. I have 2 local SQL Server instances installed on the same machine which are up and running (including Browser service). SQL Server is 2017 and 2019 (default and named instance respectively) and their Hide Instance flag is set to No.
When adding Data Link for Data Flow SSIS tasks (Destination or Source Assistant) server drop down not showing my SQL instances like that:
[image]

At the same time if I type in SQL Server instance name I can connect just fine. What can be causing my SQL instances not showing up here?

Comment: Any chance this can be related to your situation? - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b601fe13-e8e6-4217-b1c5-016112670fec/server-name-is-missing-when-connecting-to-integration-services?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: I've just applied CU8 for SQL Server 2019 and it resolved my problem, I will try to do some more checks and maybe will answer my own question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this off - you may see this problem depending on selected provider, if your provider set to "Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" you may observe empty server drop down in Data Link Properties (exactly what we have on the screenshot in the question above), and just switching your provider to "Native OLE DB\SQL Server Native Client 11.0" resolves this problem. Actually this change changes UI slightly - you won't have "Data Links..." button next to OLE DB Provider which opens up Data Link properties as per screenshot in the question but it instead you will have Server Name drop down directly in Connection Manager window under Provider drop down as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just copy your server name from sql server **MSSM** and add it manually by typing it

[image: example]